# weekdays with date-Digit number in moment js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to find WeekdayName with dateDigit in moment js.

for example: **Wednesday 13**

I have found these => `moment(date).format('dddd')`
But is returning me only **Wednesday** not digit number.

So any lead, for answer appreciates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**format** - [`dddd DD`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)

`dddd` - Day Name

`DD`   - Date

```js
console.log(moment().format('dddd DD'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```